# HTML5 video player with flash fallback with only mp4

Tags: html, flash, mp4

Can anybody help me setup a HTML5 video player with fallback on flash and only using mp4 video files? The file should be supplied from a URL (like http://www.resursecrestine.ro/download/41323).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into [videojs](http://videojs.com/). It supports MP4 and more, and has a lightweight Flash fallback.

Comment: Thank you, I already did that few days ago and it works like a charm. The only problem I have is that when using the flash solution, the seek is not working, you have to wait until the video preloads to advance in it. Do you have any idea how I could overcome this problem?

Comment: I am by no means a Flash expert, but my guess is that this might be a limitation in the Flash module they use. Sorry I can't help much more than that :/.